# Polymorphic many to many from User to Post and Category

Tags: php, many-to-many, relationship, laravel-5.1, polymorphic-associations

I need to implement a follow system like twitter but with exception a user can follow many `Post` and can follow whole `Category` or a user can follow a `User`.

I have come up with this relationship. I am using Laravel 5.1

**User Model**

```
public function followers()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_follows', 'user_id', 'follow_id');
}

public function follows()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_follows', 'follow_id', 'user_id');
}
```

and for follow a Category

**Category Model**

```
public function followers()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'category_follows', 'user_id', 'category_id');
}
```

and for Post is the same way, as you can see I need 3 tables `(user_follows, category_follows, post_follows)` to make this work.

I know there is `Polymorphic Relation` but I cant wrap my head around it.
Please help how i can simplify it. once again below are the requirements

- **User** can follow many **Posts**
- **User** can follow many **Category**
- **User** can follow many **User**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`morphedByMany` to create polymorphic many to many relations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations). Instead of having separate `*_follows` tables, you can have a single `followables` table with the following schema:

```
user_id           int      # user_id that is following something
followable_id     int      # id of the thing that is being followed
followable_type   string   # type of the thing that is being followed
```

Here's a sample implementation:

### Category, Post and User models

```
/*
 * This function gets the followers of this entity. The
 * followable_id in the followables relation would be
 * the id of this entity. 
 */
function followers() {
    return $this->morphToMany('App\User', 'followable');
}
```

### User model

```
/*
 * Gets the list of users that are followed by this user.
 */
function users() {
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\User', 'followable');
}

/*
 * Gets the list of posts that are followed by this user.
 */
function posts() {
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\User', 'followable');
}

/*
 * Gets the list of categories that are followed by this user.
 */
function categories() {
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\User', 'followable');
}
```

Note that in this case, a `User` is both morphed **by** many and morphed **to** many, creating a self-reference many to many relationship.

Every new *followable* entity you create, you will need to add the `followers()` function to that entity, and a corresponding inverse relation to the `Users` entity. You could define a `Followable` trait containing that function, and simply add `use Followable;` to the new entity you add.

Comment: Hi @john one more thing, How I will go to attach the model, for example I have a `Post` model how can i follow it, like `$post->attach(User)`, or I have to manually insert value in `followables` table. example will be perfect

Comment: Haven't tested it, but `$post->followers()->attach(User)` should work.

Comment: Hi @john, I have tried its working, thank you very much man, much appreciated

Comment: now I am getting this error white trying to get the `$post->followers()->lists('id')` DB QueryException `Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous (SQL: select `id` from `users` inner join `followables` on `users`.`id` = `followables`.`user_id` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `followables`.`followable_id` = 1 and `followables`.`followable_type` = App\Post)'`

Comment: used Laravels Collection method to get the id (`$post->followers()->get()->lists('id')`), but It will be not efficient, I just need ids any other way?

Comment: please [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799483/get-the-followers-on-a-post-efficient-way-in-laravel-5-1) if you can help