# Get the followers on a post efficient way in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I have build a follower system using Eloquent for API (thanks to [John Bupit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692591/polymorphic-many-to-many-from-user-to-post-and-category) ) but I am getting very slow query `(n+1)`, its taking 5 second for response, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692591/polymorphic-many-to-many-from-user-to-post-and-category) is the way I have done it.

I need to know is current user following current post, so I have appended the `id` of all users following on every post (which is making a lot of sql queries).

**Post Model**

```
/**
 * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = ['followers'];

/**
 * Get the list of followers of this post.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function getFollowersAttribute()
{
    return $this->followers()->get()->lists('id');
}
```

As you can see I have added an attribute `followers` on model which fetches the lists of `ids` user following.

Is there any other way I can get the following state of post for user, How can I make it faster.

I want to show Following if user is following the post with a count of total followers.

I am returning a paginated list of 20 posts per page from API as json.

**Update**

I have tried eager loading and its fast now, but how can I get only the list of user ids, not hole user model. here is my code

```
$post->with([
  'followers' => function($q) {
      $q->select('user_id'); // select id is giving Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous
},
```

and its giving me

```
followers: [
{
    user_id: 32
},
{
    user_id: 3
},
{
    user_id: 21
},
{
    user_id: 33
},
{
    user_id: 46
},
{
    user_id: 30
}

]
```

I want something like

```
followers : [45,2,45,87,12] //as array of ids
```

it will cause problem, for example if a post get 1000 follower, I bet it will be slow again, and I cant limit the `eager loaded` result

```
$q->select('user_id')->limit(20); // Limit doesn't work
```

**Other Option**

One another way will be to cache number of followers on posts table like `followers_count`and then some way I can check that logged in user is following the each post using a flag ex. `is_following`. I dont know I am lost here.

**Please help guys, how twitter, facebook has done it? to get the followers on a post and is current user following given post.**

Comment: Do you really need to add `followers` in `$appends`? This will, as you mention, query the database for each user you fetch. You can use [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to solve this `N + 1` query problem.

Comment: I want to `eager load`, but how can i get only list of ids, it will return hole user model for each, and if try to say select id, its giving error `Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous`

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) after you get `followers`.

Example:

```
$followers = array_reduce($post->followers, function ($c, $i) {
    $c[] = $i->user_id;
}, []);
```

Now the `$followers` contain all follower `id`s.